# Append Image and text together to the list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am doing a simple weather application. As you can see from the code below, I am showing 5-day forecast, I want to show as a list, but there is a problem that I can not append an image to my list elements for every day.

my js file

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var iconurl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + forecast[i].image.toString() + ".png";


            var t = document.createTextNode("Date: " + forecast[i].date.toString().substring(8, 10)
                + "/" + forecast[i].date.toString().substring(5, 7) + " "
                + "Current Temperature: " + forecast[i].temperature.toString() + " "
                + "Maximum: " + forecast[i].temperature_max.toString() + " "
                + "Minimum:  " + forecast[i].temperature_min.toString() + " "
                + "Description: " + forecast[i].text.toString() + " ");
            li.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
```

my Html file

```
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2 style="margin:5px">Weather Application</h2>
    <p id="title">You can search here.</p>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search...">
    <span onclick="gettingJSON()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">

</ul>
```

My List output like this. 
My Question about; For example, I want to add images next to the "light rain" and other 5 days as you can see below picture. How can I add it?
[image: My list output like this]

Comment: forecast[i].image.toString(), is only returning like "a10n". And that URL is working when I displayed it on a different list or div.

Comment: In that case, all you need is to create an image (`document.createElement("img");`) and place the resulting string in the `src` attribute. And append it to its respective `li`, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply didn't used this variable at all `iconurl`
You can create Image element as

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
var li = document.createElement("li"); 
var iconurl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + forecast[i].image.toString() + ".png"; 
var t = document.createTextNode("Date: " + forecast[i].date.toString().substring(8, 10) + "/" + forecast[i].date.toString().substring(5, 7) + " " + "Current Temperature: " + forecast[i].temperature.toString() + " " + "Maximum: " + forecast[i].temperature_max.toString() + " " + "Minimum: " + forecast[i].temperature_min.toString() + " " + "Description: " + forecast[i].text.toString() + " ");
var img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.src=iconurl;
img.width=20;
img.height=20;
 li.appendChild(t);
li.appendChild(img); document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li); document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you're missing:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src", iconurl);
li.appendChild(image);
```

If you want the image before the text, you should append it first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an image element, set its `src` to the url, and append it to your `li`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var iconurl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + forecast[i].image.toString() + ".png";
  var img = li.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
  img.src = iconurl;
  var t = // ...
```